# jQuery 'expand' and 'contract' image on hover - 'contract' fails

Tags: jquery, html, css

My aim is to animate an image to new dimensions on mouse-over as well as temporarily add a new css class, and to return it to its original dimensions (and remove the added class) on mouse-out.

My code works fine on mouse-over.  On mouse-out the added class is removed, however the image dimensions are not restored to the original width and height.

HTML:

```
<img src='img.jpg' alt='' class='pulse'>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  // set global img width and height
  var width_pulse_img = 0;
  var height_pulse_img = 0;
  $('img.pulse').hover(function () {
    // onMouseOver: read original width and height on FIRST mouseover
    if (!width_pulse_img) width_pulse_img = $(this).css('width');
    if (!height_pulse_img) height_pulse_img = $(this).css('height');
    // set img expansion ratio and compute new dimensions
    var float_exp = 1 + 0.1;
    var ww = (float_exp*parseInt(width_pulse_img, 10)).toString();
    var hh = (float_exp*parseInt(height_pulse_img, 10)).toString();
    // animate to new dimensions
    $(this).addClass('hover').stop().animate({
      width: ww + 'px',
      height: hh + 'px'
    }, 200);
  }, function () {
    // onMouseOut: animate back to original dimensions: 
    $(this).removeClass('hover').stop().animate({
      // THIS IS THE PART THAT DOES NOT WORK
      width: width_pulse_img + 'px',
      height: height_pulse_img + 'px'
    }, 400);
  });
});
```

I have tested in Firefox 12.0, Chrome and IE 9.0 and the behaviour is the same.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6zvg/) demonstrating the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/z6zvg/1/, using `.width()` and `.height()` instead of `.css(...` does the trick.

Comment: @Joy: Great, thanks. Still don't understand why it fails though.  Anyway, please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: check my updated answer to find out why your's one is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.width()` and `.height()` instead of `.css(..)` does the trick. So use it like

```
width_pulse_img = $(this).width();
height_pulse_img = $(this).height();
```

And it will work fine.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/z6zvg/1/

And about why it fails I am still not sure about why that is happening. But while using `.css()` it's always retaining the change in `width and height`.

**Update: The reason behind**

As the doc says in [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

> The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter
>   returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former
>   returns a value **with units intact (for example, 400px)**.

So after first assignment of these two lines

```
width_pulse_img = $(this).css('width');   // 220px
height_pulse_img = $(this).css('height'); // 237px
```

So they have `px` already as you have used `.css(`.

And they later when your are using

```
  width: width_pulse_img + 'px',   // becoming 220pxpx
  height: height_pulse_img + 'px'  // 237pxpx
```

So it's ignoring the whole thing and not contracting the image. But as you have used `parseInt` `expanding` is working fine.

**Working version With .css():**  http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/z6zvg/4/